# Get the day position ... in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How I can get the position of a day inside a week like:

If it's sunday = 0
 monday =1
 tuesday=2
 ...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) for this:

```
NSArray *days = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday", nil];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
                    [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday] - 1;

NSLog(@"it is %@ today.", [days objectAtIndex:weekday]);

[gregorian release];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[NSDateFormatter weekdaySymbols]` will return an `NSArray` of the weekday symbols.

Comment: @Woobie Yeah, sure, but that doesn't tell you which one of those is the current one! ;-)

Comment: I guess I read the question wrong; I thought he wanted to know how to find out that 0 is Sunday and 1 is Monday, etc.